The theory of Groebner bases in Jordan case
There are many papers regarding spreading the theory of Groebner-Shirshov bases from Lie algebras to other nonassociative algebras. Also, it has been studied for associative algebras with operators and etc. Regarding Jordan algebras, I have not found any paper in the literature for Groebner-Shirshov bases for Jordan case, what specific features make them hard to study this theory for Jordan algebras?
